# URL with query string in javascript

Tags: javascript, url, query-string, embed

My plugin takes a video url and parses it in a modal window as `%id%`. However, it does not currently know how to handle urls with a query string in them. Example: `https://player.vimeo.com/video/605783608?h=493d2ee578` Everything after `?h=` is removed.

I think this line is the problem: `embedSrc = embedSrc.substr(embedSrc.lastIndexOf(this.id)+this.id.length, embedSrc.length);`

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/bluehelmet/542ztfyh/37/) also is the fiddle for testing.

Javascript:

```
$.magnificPopup.registerModule(IFRAME_NS, {

    options: {
        srcAction: 'iframe_src',

        patterns: {
            youtube: {
                index: 'youtube.com', 
                id: 'v=', 
                src: '//www.youtube.com/embed/%id%?autoplay=1'
            },
            vimeo: {
                index: 'vimeo.com/',
                id: '/',
                src: '//player.vimeo.com/video/%id%?autoplay=1'
            }
        }
    },

        getIframe: function(item, template) {
            var embedSrc = item.src;
            var iframeSt = mfp.st.iframe;
                
            $.each(iframeSt.patterns, function() {
                if(embedSrc.indexOf( this.index ) > -1) {
                    if(this.id) {
                        if(typeof this.id === 'string') {
                            embedSrc = embedSrc.substr(embedSrc.lastIndexOf(this.id)+this.id.length, embedSrc.length);
                        } else {
                            embedSrc = this.id.call( this, embedSrc );
                        }
                    }
                    embedSrc = this.src.replace('%id%', embedSrc );
                    return false; // break;
                }
            });
            
            var dataObj = {};
            if(iframeSt.srcAction) {
                dataObj[iframeSt.srcAction] = embedSrc;
            }
            mfp._parseMarkup(template, dataObj, item);
            mfp.updateStatus('ready');
            return template;
        }
    }
});
```

[Full js file](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.0.0/jquery.magnific-popup.js)